# How do you get elasticsearch to create unique ids for objects created via REST?

Tags: .net, elasticsearch, nest

**The short version**: how do I get elastic search to generate an identity for an object, and use that as both "_id" and get it set in the object.

**The long version**: In a restful API, I don't usually know the id of the object that I'm inserting into a database. For example, I might create a recipe for "Pasta Salad"

My rest call (and body) would be something like this

```
POST /api/v1/recipe

{
  "title": "Pasta Salad",
  "details": "..."  
}
```

In C# my representation for that is something like this...

```
public class Recipe
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Details { get; set; }
}
```

I wouldn't expect a caller to know how to generate an id that hadn't been used, and I'd expect whatever stores the object to create an id. Typically in a database I'd have a sequence/generated as identity column to do this.

A read would then return me the object with the next id value populated.

How do I get elasticsearch to generate the Id property of the C# object when creating a document, so that this is unique, and then also use that as the _id value in elastic search?

This is what I have in ConnectionSettings

```
var connectionSettings = new ConnectionSettings(elasticSearchUri)
    .DefaultIndex(elasticSearchDefaultIndex)
    .DefaultMappingFor<Recipe>(r => r.IdProperty(x => x.Id));
```

This is how I'm creating the document in elasticsearch...

```
        var recipe = new Recipe
        {
            Title = "Pasta Salad",
            Details = "..."
        };

        var response = await _elasticClient.IndexDocumentAsync(recipe);
```

Browsing http://localhost:9200/default/_doc/_search

... so elasticsearch has generates a unique "_id" value, but doesn't set "Id" on the object itself

```
"hits":{"total":{"value":1,"relation":"eq"},"max_score":1.0,"hits":[{"_index":"default","_type":"_doc","_id":"3oeo8W8BfYYLXBBW8Vac","_score":1.0,"_source":{"title":"Pasta Salad","details":"..."}}]}}
```

If I include an id (in my C# object), the _id and the object's id are both set as expected, problem is, I wouldn't know the id at insert time, how do I get elastic search to get the next unique id?

```
"hits":{"total":{"value":1,"relation":"eq"},"max_score":1.0,"hits":[{"_index":"default","_type":"_doc","_id":"1","_score":1.0,"_source":{"id":1,"title":"Pasta Salad","details":"..."}}]}}
```

Answer (score -2):

You can assign the "_id" value to be whatever you want.  So in your case, assigning the Id value of the object to the _id property of the Elasticsearch document will work.

Comment: Not quite what I meant. How would I know which unique id's are available? For example, when using a database with an identity column I'd insert the row (without an id) and the id would be set for me. If I have to set the id myself I have to query elasticsearch for the max id, incrementing the id by one, then create the document in elasticsearch with that id, during which time another instance may have used the id. I also noted this in my question. Do you see what I mean?

Comment: Would GET index/_doc/{id} work?  My suggestion is to generate a UUID or use the auto generated id instead of a sequential key.

Comment: How do you "use the auto generated id"?

Comment: @EricPabst - Omit the property and ES will auto generate it for you. This is my current set-up no property is defined on the client side prior to bulk insert.

Comment: @BKB - does the property in c# have to named specifically: "_id" ?